# SUM of column in PHP gives wrong output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

I am facing trouble while executing and doing the SUM of the column but the code is showing the wrong output. I tried to fix this through `GROUP BY` also but the same wrong output result. I believe this is executing times of common row existing in DB.

I truly never facing this issue before.
Please help me , How to I fix this issue and what should be the correct SQL in PHP

```
*Table CR_table*

ID | credit | components_key
----------------------------
1  | 400    | 202012162458
----------------------------
2  | 300    | 202012162458


*Table DR_table*

ID | req_debit  | components_key
----------------------------
1  | 100    | 202012162458
----------------------------


SELECT DISTINCT SUM(credit)-SUM(req_debit) FROM CR_table LEFT JOIN DR_table ON CR_table.components_key = DR_table.components_key WHERE DR_table.transaction_type = 'OA' AND CR_table.components_key = '202012162458' GROUP BY CR_table.components_key
```

*OUTPUT = 500 (BUT the Output Should be 600)*

OPENING BALANCE

```
SELECT SUM(AMT) as OpeningBalance (SUM(CASE WHEN DR.insert_date < '2020-12-29' THEN CR.credit - DR.debit ELSE 0 END) FROM CR_table CR WHERE CR.components_key = '202012162458'
UNION ALL SELECT -req_debit AMT FROM DR_table DR WHERE DR.transaction_type = 'OA' AND DR.components_key = '202012162458') t  `but Opeing is also not working
```

`

Comment: Consider storing debits and credits in the same table.

Answer (score 1):

When you are joining two tables, it is producing `2(credit)*1(debit) = 2 records` in which you have 2 different credits and one single debit repeated in both rows so you are getting 500 (`400 + 300 - 100 - 100`) output.

You can also use `UNION ALL` as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(AMT) FROM
(SELECT credit AMT FROM CR_table CR  
 WHERE CR.components_key = '202012162458'
UNION ALL
SELECT -req_debit AMT FROM DR_table DR 
 WHERE DR.transaction_type = 'OA' 
   AND DR.components_key = '202012162458') t
```

Comment: error comes =` #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: Done!! need to give alias to sub-query. See the answer now

Comment: @Popeye Thank you , you are genius , could you tell me one thing which is which tough for me.. in case '2020-12-27' is by start business date `openingBalance` by default `0` I want when I see the report on `2020-12-29` above code will show the output as openingbal on `2020-12-29`

Comment: I think you should ask another question as it is tough for me to get the question from comment. and Yes, you can accept this answer if it resolved your issue.

Comment: Sir I updated the question this is bit some small error. Please help me.. i dont have must reputation to ask new question.

Comment: No, you can not update the question like that. Ask new question for it. We are ready to help you. In SO, your question must be focused and future reader must get the quality answers from this question/answer.

Comment: as you said, I creted a post but popeye.. Pls help me `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65517418/php-sum-as-opening-and-closing-in-sql-not-working` your answer was not working